# No posts found within the Wordpress loop based on custom arguments

Tags: php, wordpress

I've set one simply parameter in my args array but not getting any of the appropriate posts through.

With use of Advanced Custom Fields, I created a 'Select' option in the 'post' types, and the option being 'Featured: Yes'. About 4 are set as featured but still states no posts are found.

** I've provided a screenshot of the page. As you'll see, there are posts on the bottom half of the page which are coming through using the standard loop, but I've setup a new loop to display just Featured posts at the top. Maybe I am meant to end the global loop first?

Here is my current setup:

```
<?php 

// args
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'feature_post',
    'meta_value' => 'Yes'
);

// get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>

<ul class="bxslider">

    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <div class="featured-article">
            <div class="category-label">Health</div>
            <i class="category-label-end"></i>
            <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <div class="featured-article-title">
                <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>

<?php else : echo '<p style="color:#fff;">no posts</p>'; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

Advanced Custom Fields

[image]

A post that has been set to Featured.

[image]

Post Page:

[image]

Comment: Hi, first what is `numberposts => -1` ?,

Comment: @Mauro - it means return all rows (don't limit / paginate the query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because you can have several checkboxes in the one field, meaning ACF needs to store the value as an array, rather than a single string.

I just did a test, and this is the `meta_value` I get based on your setup:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:3:"Yes";}
```

which won't match the literal `Yes` you're using.

In this particular case, I'd try using ACF's `True / False` field type.  If true, it stores `1` in the `meta_value` field, which would work with the approach you're using.

Comment: Ok yeah the True/False field type worked instead, so I'll go ahead with that for now. Thanks!